# Text field to url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am making a form with many text fields on it. some fields require that a number be entered. The purpose of this form is so that a tracking number can be entered or an order number or another number and each of these will (once submitted) load a new url in a new window with the specific number appended to the url in question. Once an order number is entered I want the form to go to the following address: website.com/ordernumberfromform

I have hit a wall though, on this input I require that it is simply website.com/ordernumberfromforminput ie no id= or anything else just taking the value that was entered and appending to the url after the / . I do not need validation to check if the number entered is valid etc as the url that it points to will give an error if this is the case. Simply taking the value from the text field and slotting it in after the / at the end of url.

Has anyone else come across this? surely there is no need for javascript or serverside scripting in this instance, seems like making a mountain out of a mole-hill... I have done my best to research this but cant seem to find the solution. any direction would be great.

below is a sample of my code.

```
<div id="orderidfield">
<form action="https://www.website.com/" method="get" target="_blank">
<input type="search" name="orderNumber"/>
<!!-- I want this to take an order number and post to the url     (www.url.com/ordernumberthatisentered) It is a simple request but I cannot figure this     out.... it keeps adding in th eid and an = sign -->
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You will a URL rewrite in PHP to handle a URL like `www.url.com/ordernumberthatisentered`.

Comment: use method="post" not "get"

Comment: @ChaseC, how will you append it to the URL with a POST? OP: You don't think you need JavaScript or do you not want to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving you a solution **using js and html** only:
Your HTML:

```
<div id="orderidfield">
<input type="text" name="orderNumber" id="search"/>
    <button onClick="search()">Search</button>
</div>
```

And here is your script

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
function search()
{
    var number=document.getElementById("search").value;
    window.open("http://www.url.com/"+number);
}

</script>
```

And here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/piyushkmr/mEfmu/2/

Answer (score 0):

I've make a workaround using another post form and changing the action using javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/vf9rb/1/

Part of the html is like this

```
<form id="oldform" action="www.example.com">
    <input type="search" name="orderNumber"/>
</form>

<form id="trueform" action="www.example.com" method="post">
</form>

<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

and the javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        var orderNumber = $("#oldform input").val();
        var oldAction = $("#trueform").attr("action");
        var newAction = oldAction + "/" + orderNumber;
        $("#trueform").attr("action", newAction);
        $("#trueform").submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the text field to a variable and doing this.

open.window(url)

That should get you what you want.